# Como fazer o pedido à API de forma a mostrar apenas imagens cuja largura é maior do que a altura?

Tags: javascript

Olá! Estou atualmente a desenvolver uma aplicação web para um trabalho universitário que integra várias APIs. Relativamente a uma das API, a Unsplash encontro-me com um problema no código seguinte:

```
function showImages(search) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.getJSON('https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=' + search + '&per_page=24&client_id=' + APIKey, function (data) {
                    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
                    $.each(data.results, function (i, image) {
                        var imageURL = image.urls.regular;
                        var imageWidth = image.width;
                        var imageHeight = image.height;
                        if (imageWidth > imageHeight) {
                            $('#output').append('<div class="image"><img src="' + imageURL + '"></div>');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        }

        // wrapping in $(function() { ... }) ensures the page is loaded and <form id="imagesearch"> exists
        $(function () {
            $('#imagesearch').on("submit", function () {
                const search = $('#search').val().trim(); // grab search term
                if (search.length) showImages(search); // don't search if field is blank
                return false; // very important, this prevents regular form submission
            });
        });
```

Como podem observar no url existe um excerto "&per_page=" que controla o número de imagens que devem ser mostradas (neste caso, 24). Porém devido à condição "if" que mostra apenas as imagens cuja largura é superior à altura, que foi criada apenas por questões estéticas, não são mostradas 24 imagens.

Objectivo:
O meu objectivo é forçar a que sejam mostradas 24 imagens em todos os casos, que respeitem aquela condição if, isto é, que sejam 24 imagens cuja largura é superior à altura.

O que já fiz:
Já coloquei o valor "&per_page" igualado a uma variável "numimage", mas não consigo decidir, onde deverá ser definida e trabalhada.

Comment: Olá, Fábio. Existem algumas possibilidades irei falar algumas para que você possa pensar e escolher a que melhor se encaixa no sua fluxo. Todas remetem a criação de uma variável que irá controlar a quantidade de fotos validas a condição [IF] . 
1°) Com a variável, caso não atinja as 24 imagens válidas, será feita uma nova requisição para atingir o limite, quando fosse atingido você faria um break.
2°) Com a variável, você poderia aumentar o número de fotos da requisição e utilizaria o contador para efetuar o break no processo.
Espero ter ajudado na sua linha de raciocínio.

Comment: Acho que vc deveria puxar um número grande de imagens de forma que seja provável que haja pelo menos 24 imagens com o critério width > height. Fazer novas requisições como sugeriu o @MarcusItalo acho não ser boa solução porque terá que ficar fazendo requisições à API mais de uma vez. Seria melhor puxar logo umas 200 imagens e condicionar o .each a rodar apenas 24 vezes, ou seja, das 200 imagens, quando forem encontradas 24 com width > height, você cancela o laço.